# How to use git on remote server (and vscode)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have my programming code directories in my home directory on Linux `/home/maxg`, with different folders for python, c, php, and bash files... (like `/home/maxg/python`); each have a vsCode workspace file.
I also have a local web server on another machine, which is a copy of the externally website running on PHP.

When I connected with vsCode to the local web server, vsCode could not cope with the amount of files, because the web directory contains thousands of photos, I would like to exclude from git and vsCode.

While vsCode and git work on a local machine as intended, I am at a loss when it comes to configuring both for working on 'remote' machines.

1. Do I create a local workspace file on my machine and point it to the local web server?
2. Does the local web server need git installed to have a .gitignore file?
3. Or do I manage this on my local machine? If so, where do I put the directory and ignore statements?

[edit_1:] This query is about working with vsCode/git on my local machine, but pointing to the local web server. (The external web server is updated via FTP.)

Comment: Are you wanting to use git as a method of deployment?

Comment: That would be nice to; but too complicated for me right now (I use FileZilla to update the remote with the local contents). No, this is about using vsCode by pointing it to the local web server, w/o generating a vsCode error due to too many files in some of the sub directories containing non-PHP files.